# Broke off Office 365 install, can't uninstall or reinstall

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

My new surface book managed to break off the install of office 365 x32 when it was at about 8% through. Laptop rebooted and I figured I'd try the x64 version instead.

Now I'm getting messages (on both the x32 and x64 installer) that an install is in progress and it refuses to continue.

I cannot uninstall the previous install because it is not in my "Uninstall a program" list.

How do I fully cancel the started install, which I can't seem to find now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Windows Installer has left in an error state.

First, try this [Microsoft Fix-It](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) utility, reboot, and try again.  If that doesn't do the trick, you can fix the Microsoft Installer state, alternatively try a third-party cleanup tool - come back here after trying the linked fix below and let us know how you get on.

An alternative link suggested by Microsoft is [this one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-installing-office-365-office-2016-and-office-2013-35ff2def-e0b2-4dac-9784-4cf212c1f6c2#bkmk_problemsinstalling), but try the first link first.

You can redownload Office by going to [the Office Portal](https://stores.office.com/myaccount/home.aspx) and redownloading.  Note, this will require you to have already have Office365 on your account - or you can download the trial.

Comment: The install is not listed in the Fix It utility. How do I find the product code?

Comment: I can see entries to stuff like Microsoft.Office.Excel_16000 etc in the registry

Comment: Don't hack the registry.  Have you tried the second item in my list?

Comment: I want to try the first but aka.ms times out for me. Both laptop via wifi as well as iPhone over 4g I might add

Comment: Did you select a problem uninstalling, or a problem installing?

Comment: Uninstalling... I’m trying installing now

Comment: If that doesn't work either, use the second link instead - the first is a generic Windows Installer fix, the second is an actual Office tool.  The AKA.MS works for me as the tool downloads straight away.  I can upload to my dropbox if needed.

Comment: second one did the trick once the page loaded. Thanks